# does 'response.clear()' remove content and header?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, response

I need to know if `Response.Clear()` just clear content or it also remove the headers?
in other word if I use `Response.Clear()`, do I also need to use `Response.ClearHeader()` or not ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525713(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AS [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525713%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) SAYS

> The Clear method erases any buffered HTML output.   However, the Clear
>   method erases only the response body;    it does not erase response
>   headers.

To clear header use `Response.ClearHeaders();`

Comment: It would appear that the .NET Response.Clear() method is provided for backwards compatibility with classic ASP applications. Response.ClearContent() performs the same function.